# Modify a member variable outside the class object and have changes in the class object

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, object, numpy, reference

I have a class in python :

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.obj = None
  def setObj(self, npArray):
    self.obj = npArray
  def getObj(self):
    return self.obj
```

In another python script I instantiate an object of the class A and set "obj" and then get it some where else

```
objOfA.setObj(npArray)

''' Some operations '''

objOut = objOfA.getObj()

''' More operations '''
np.append(objOut,[0.25])  ## Here np.append is used just as an example. There can be many other algebraic operations. 

''' operations using objOfA '''
```

Here in the operations above using objOfA, I want to see the modified array (appended with 0.25).

In C++ it is quite possible using pointers or references. But I am having hard time doing this in python. I understand how and when python uses references to the objects. By my problem is as soon as I do

```
objOut = objOfA.getObj()
```

I am getting a copy of the array but not a reference into `objOut`.

Is there a way in which I can do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, [`np.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) returns a new array (emphasis mine):

> A copy of *arr* with *values* appended to *axis*. **Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.** If *axis* is None, *out* is a flattened array.

So you would have to assign the return value back to your object:

```
objOut.setObj(np.append(objOut.getObj(), [0.25]))
```

Note that the use of getter and setter methods is discouraged in Python, you should just access the object directly:

```
objOut.obj = np.append(objOut.obj, [0.25])
```

---

If you are not dependent on *numpy* arrays, you could just use lists which are mutable:

```
objOut.obj = [1, 2, 3]
objOut.obj.append(0.25)
objOut.obj.extend([4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... I used np.append  as an example for an operation. there can be other mathematical operations. Also about the getter and setter functions. Yes I agree. There are also instances where the obj is passed through a hierarchy of  class objects. Will it work also in those cases ? Also Yes I am dependent on numpy arrays .

Comment: In general avoid expresions like `x=fun(x)`, `x=x-...`; use ones like `x-=...`, x[:]=...`. Also learn the difference between views and copies.  And you cannot grow an array inplace.  Test things like `id(x)` and `x.__aray_interface__`

Comment: Yeah, it doesn’t matter if its `objOut.obj` or `objOut.obj.and.more.hierachies.obj`. And it really depends on the operation. Things that change the dimension of a numpy array usually do not modify the array in-place, while mathematical operations on the numpy array can be performed in-place (using assigning operators like `+=` or `*=`).